# Make a virtualbox hard drive from virtual block device

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, lfs

I'm trying to create LFS (linux from scratch) but copying to usb is so slow so I created a virtual disk file of 3GB using created partition and formatted to ext4.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=./lfs.img bs=1M count=3000
sudo fdisk lfs.img  #created partition
sudo losetup -Pf --show lfs.img

vaibhav@vaibhav:/mnt$ lsblk
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0       7:0    0     3G  0 loop
├─loop0p1 259:0    0   2.5G  0 part /mnt
└─loop0p2 259:1    0   499M  0 part


sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0p1
sudo mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt
```

then I copied my linux packages from host to virtual drive here is my linux fs on virtual drive.

```
vaibhav@vaibhav:/mnt$ ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lfs  lib  lib64  lost+found  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

So now I want to boot this drive on my Virtualbox how I can add this loopback device to act as a hard drive for virtualbox.

**EDITS**
I was able to convert to VDI file but when I change in raw directory I have to recreate this VDI every time and I think doing 3GB every time it not good for SSD. So is there any way I can direclty mount directory as Hard drive in Virtualbox?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454899/how-to-convert-flat-raw-disk-image-to-vmdk-for-virtualbox-or-vmplayer

Comment: Thanks @ArtemS.Tashkinov worked perfectly but now the thing is if I make changes to raw disk I have to recreate this vdi file. Is there any way that I don't have to recreated every time when I make changes?

Comment: What kind of changes? You could use `qemu-nbd` to work with vdi files directly.

Comment: Changes like I update linux kernel or install a package or update grub.conf

Comment: You could use qemu-nbd to work with vdi files directly.